# Expected value of 3-repeated keys for a cuckoo hash table

Tags: probability, expected-value, computational-statistics

I'm trying to solve a problem for my data structures class and am having problem computing the expectation for this scenario. I have wrote the question to be as independed from CS as possible

I have a two tables $t_1$, $t_2$ each of size $N/2$ cells. Suppose I have two truely random functions $h_1$ that maps keys to random cells in $t_1$ and $h_2$ that maps keys to $t_2$. There are $n$ keys, and each key will be mapped (using the random functions) to  $t_1$ and $t_2$.

What is the expected number of dirty triples that will occur. A dirty triple is any 3 key, $k_1,k_2,k_3$ where random function 1 maps all the keys to the same cell in $t_1$ and random function 2 map all the keys to the same cell in $t_2$. In other words, I want to know $$E[\text{given some 3 keys, $k_1,k_2,k_3$ is a dirty triple }]\\ = ~h_1(k_1) = h_1(k_2) = h_1(k_3)~and~h_2(k_1)=h_2(k_2)=h_3(k_3) \\ E[X]$$

Is my answer correct. $$E[X] = \text{total triples} \cdot \Pr(\text{any triple is a dirty triple}) \\ \binom{n}{3} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^6}$$

My reasoning is that the probability that a key is mapped to a particular cell is one divided by the number of cells in that table. We apply the product rule for both tables since the mapping of 1 key is indpenednet from a mapping of another.

Some of my classmates disgree and argue that it should be $\binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^4}$ instead. I am wondering who is right (if either) and what the reasoning is.

Comment: "Random function" leaves too much unspecified.  Do you know the probabilities these functions assign to to each cell?  Normally they are constructed to assign equal probabilities to each cell, but it's not clear that's what you have in mind.

Comment: Sorry, each function maps to cells in an equally random way. And by that, i think what I mean is uniformily distributed. Also, they are independent